Hubbard Model Hamiltonian using Number operator
In Hubbard model one can write Hamiltonian to be,
$$\hat{H} = \sum_{ij\sigma} t_{ij} c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma} + \frac{U_H}{2} \sum_{i} \sum_{\sigma} n_{i\sigma} n_{i,-\sigma}$$
where, $n_{i\sigma} = c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{i\sigma}$ is the number operator .
Using the anticommutation relation of fermion one can write,
\begin{equation}
n_{i\sigma}^2 = n_{i\sigma} \tag{1}                              
\end{equation}
and using this one arrives at,
\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \sum_{ij\sigma} \left( t_{ij} - \frac{1}{2} U_H \delta_{ij} \right) c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma} + \frac{1}{2} U_H \sum_{i} \sum_{\sigma,\sigma'} n_{i\sigma} n_{i,\sigma'} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
My question is, how one can use equation (1) in the given Hamiltonian to get equation (2)?

I think it is easiest to go in reverse. Starting with Equation (3) we have:
\begin{align}
\hat{H} &= \sum_{ij\sigma} \left(t_{ij} - \frac{1}{2} U_H \delta_{ij} \right) c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma} + \frac{1}{2} U_H \sum_{i} \sum_{\sigma,\sigma'} n_{i\sigma} n_{i,\sigma'} \\ &= \sum_{ij\sigma} t_{ij}c^\dagger_{i\sigma}c_{j\sigma} + \frac{U_H}{2}\sum_{i\sigma}\left(-n_{i\sigma} + \sum_{\sigma'}n_{i\sigma}n_{i\sigma'}\right) \\ & =
\sum_{ij\sigma} t_{ij}c^\dagger_{i\sigma}c_{j\sigma} + \frac{U_H}{2}\sum_{i\sigma}\left(-n_{i\sigma} + n_{i\sigma}n_{i\sigma} + n_{i\sigma}n_{i,-\sigma}\right) \tag{1}.
\end{align}
In the third equality we have expanded the sum in $\sigma'$. Now, letting $n_{i\sigma}n_{i\sigma} = n_{i\sigma}^2 = n_{i\sigma}$ in (1), we see that:
\begin{align}
\hat{H} & = \sum_{ij\sigma} t_{ij}c^\dagger_{i\sigma}c_{j\sigma} + \frac{U_H}{2}\sum_{i\sigma}\left(-n_{i\sigma} + n_{i\sigma} + n_{i\sigma}n_{i,-\sigma}\right) \\ &= \sum_{ij\sigma} t_{ij}c^\dagger_{i\sigma}c_{j\sigma} + \frac{U_H}{2}\sum_{i\sigma}n_{i\sigma}n_{i,-\sigma},
\end{align}
as desired. Let me know if anything is unclear!
